# put UIButtons at random position

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, cgrectmake

How to put 4 UIButtons at  4 random positions only.
I have an app that has 4 UIButtons every time I press an change position button the  UIButtons should change there position like 
Button1 moves to the position of Button4 and Button4 to any other Button's position randomly

when I use this code there is no change in buttons positions

-(void)changeButtonPosition
{

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(222,246,27,21)]];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(80, 246, 27, 21)]];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(165, 324, 27, 21)]];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(222, 324, 27, 21)]];


  NSUInteger count = [array count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
btn1.frame = [((NSValue *)[array objectAtIndex:0]) CGRectValue];
btn2.frame = [((NSValue *)[array objectAtIndex:1]) CGRectValue];
btn3.frame = [((NSValue *)[array objectAtIndex:2]) CGRectValue];
btn4.frame = [((NSValue *)[array objectAtIndex:3]) CGRectValue];
```

}
Thanks !

Comment: you need to write a function , which changes the (x,y) of every button, thats it. try for yourself , if you need any help after that, then post your tried code.

Comment: I need to move the button to random position, If i change the (x,y)  then the position will remain at the place I decided it should move to random position out of 4 frames

Comment: hey man can by putting all frames in nasarry and change the array according to ur choice and assign to the buttuns frame

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, like pawan commented: 
Write a function that returns a CGPoint (which contains the x and y position, created randomly), and in your viewDidLoad, generate 4 random sets of coordinates for your 4 buttons. This will set up your 4 buttons at 4 random locations.

Then in your button handlers, do the same, and move the buttons around from there.

Should be pretty simple.

Edit:

To have a method return a (x,y) location, you need to do something more like this:

```
 - (CGPoint)randomPoint {
   int random_X = arc4Random() % WIDTH;
   int random_Y = arc4Random() % HEIGHT;
   return CGPointMake(random_X, random_Y);
 }
```

Then your calling method needs to do something with this returned CGPoint value.

Edit 2:

If you need just a frame out of your 4 button frames, then this is what you need to do: 
Create an NSArray with the 4 button frames, and then generate a list of 4 numbers that are random permutations of the list [0, 1, 2, 3] and get your "random" frame that way.

Comment: To do which part? The random location generation or the button handling?

Comment: -(void)muh
{
    int x_coord = arc4random() % 321; 
    int y_coord = arc4random() % 481; 
    
    CGRect newframe = [btn1 frame];
    newframe.origin.x = x_coord;
    newframe.origin.y = y_coord;
    btn1.frame = newframe;
}
the above function generates random position from all over the screen, but i need to generate the position either (65,246) or (222,246) or (65,324) or (222,324)

Comment: see my edited answer. You can play with how you initialize random_X and random_Y so that they are within certain bounds that you want.

Comment: Your not randomly assigning the buttons indexes, but just giving them back there original position. Try randomly assigning the cgrect values

Answer (score 0):

Store the position (x,y) of each button in an array.

Then generate a set of random number so that no number is in their previous place.

for example:

1,2,3,4 - initial state

2,4,1,3 - in an random iteration.

Then just took the position from the array and add the buttons to that position.

Hope this helps. :)